# How to to prevent markPoint labels overlapping?

Tags: javascript, visualization, linechart, echarts

In the following example, label overlapping is prevented on the right Yaxis with `labelLayout: {moveOverlap: 'shiftY'}` and `labelLine: {show: true}`. But I didn't find how to prevent this on the left Yaxis:

```js
var dom = document.getElementById('chart-container');
var myChart = echarts.init(dom, null, {
  renderer: 'canvas',
  useDirtyRect: false
});
var app = {};

var option;

const dataset = [[150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260], [230, 160, 70, 135, 147, 140, 110], [145, 147, 260, 340, 290, 110, 115]];
const entity = ['Mangolia', 'Mitzerland','Torsica'];

const seriesList = [];
for (const index in dataset) {
  const row = dataset[index];
  seriesList.push({
    type: 'line',
    data: row,
    name:entity[index],
    labelLayout: {moveOverlap: 'shiftY'},
    labelLine: {show: true},
    endLabel: {
      show: true,
      formatter: '{a} = {c}'
    },
    markPoint: {
      symbolSize: 0,
      label: {
        position: 'left', 
        formatter: (params)=> `${params.value} = ${params.data.coord[1]}`
      },
      data: [{coord: [0, row[0]], value: entity[index]}]
    }
  });
}

option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    boundaryGap: false,
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    offset: -260
  },
  series: seriesList
};

if (option && typeof option === 'object') {
  myChart.setOption(option);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', myChart.resize);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#chart-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Basic Line Chart - Apache ECharts Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart-container"></div>
  <script src="https://fastly.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.4.3/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How could I prevent overlapping for markpoint labels?